# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предлокении?

Tags: пунктуация

Автомобили, с даты выпуска которых прошло не более 5 лет, проходят проверку каждые 2 года, а автомобили, выпущенные более 5 лет назад или год выпуска которых не установлен – 1 раз в год.

Answer (score 2):

*Автомобили, с даты выпуска которых прошло не более 5 лет, проходят проверку каждые 2 года, а автомобили, выпущенные более 5 лет назад или год выпуска которых не установлен, – 1 раз в год.*

Запятую после слова "установлен" нужно поставить, так как она закрывает конструкцию, требующую обособления. Тире оставляем на месте пропущенных членов предложения "проходят проверку"

Comment: Екатерина, а вы уверены, что запятая не поглощается тире, как, например, в случае с вводными словами: Чичиков велел остановиться по двум причинам: с одной стороны, чтобы дать отдохнуть лошадям, с другой — чтобы и самому отдохнуть и подкрепиться (запятая перед придаточной частью «поглощается» тире);  Как-то странно смотрится конструкция, вы встречали где-нибудь подобные примеры? Спасибо.

Comment: В примере с Чичиковым тире замещает часть вводной конструкции (стороны). Запятая и тире после усечённой вводной конструкции смотрелась бы очень странно. Тире в этом случае действительно замещает и опущенное"стороны", и запятую. У нас другой случай.

Comment: Случай действительно другой, поэтому мне и хотелось увидеть реальный пример из литературы. Мне как-то вариант без закрывающей запятой больше нравится, как будто эта запятая не на месте.

Comment: Если какую-то конструкцию надо выделить запятыми с двух сторон и после нее поставить тире — нужно ставить и запятую, и тире. Запятая не "поглощается". Мне тоже часто кажется, что она излишня, но формально запятая необходима: бывает так, что выделенная запятыми часть содержит внутри тире, и если бы тире поглощало запятую, было бы трудно понять, закончилась выделенная часть или это внутреннее тире.